# disposing object during Error handling in entlib 5

Tags: c#, exception

I saw the following example in MSDN.

```
exManager.Process(() =>GetDataSet("GetAllCustomers"), "Data Access Policy");
```

Any idea/technique in disposing db connection or file handle if any in `GetDataSet` method?
For example, should a finally block be added and how? Please advise.

Comment: This question does not match the example that you have provided `user2013710` you have not mentioned where exactly you are getting the error as well as what the exact error is .. wrapping your code around a `using` clause is fine but how do we know if that's where the error is truly happening.. you have shown very little code not very helpful

Answer (score 0):

C# has a really handy `using` operator:

```
using (var db = GetDbContext())
{
     GetDataSet(db, "GetAllCustomers");// data access code
}
```

The above block is effectively equivalent to:

```
{
    DbContext db;
    try
    {
        var db = GetDataSet(db, "GetAllCustomers");
         // data access code
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The context will be disposed at the end of the block, regardless of whether an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks..but what if the a file/db object is created inside GetDataSet and exception occurs how can I dispose off the file/db object?

Comment: @user2013710: The same principle applies. Just put your `using` statement around the creation of the db object inside `GetDataSet`.

Comment: I have still not started using this just wanted to check if it can used in any scenario. for e-g StreamReader reader=new  StreamReader(winDir + "\\system.ini");
          
            do
            {
                addListItem(reader.ReadLine());
            }   
            while(reader.Peek() != -1);
        }      
          Assume these are the lines of code in GetDataSet(though name is not relevant!) will the reader object be closed and disposed if any error occurs?

Comment: @user2013710: The code you posted doesn't include a `using` statement, but if it did then yes, the reader would be disposed (and therefore closed) at the end of the using block whether or not an error occurs. The `using` statement can be used with any type that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: Thanks. Understood. To clarify,for types that does implement IDisposable we can create a wrapper class which implements IDisposable.

Comment: @user2013710: Most types that don't implement disposable don't have any reason to be cleaned up. Otherwise they ought to implement IDisposable.